Adding schema.org data to breadcrumb
I am using Breadcrumb NavXT and Filter Everything. I am trying to add the product category name to the trail for a custom archive page (not taxonomy archive)
I was able to do something utilizing breadcrumb author’s example and filter author's function. Here is my code:
add_action('bcn_after_fill', 'my_static_breadcrumb_adder');
function my_static_breadcrumb_adder($breadcrumb_trail)
{
   $output = flrt_selected_filter_terms();

   $w1 = array_keys($output)[0];
   $x1 = $output[$w1]["values"][0];
   $y1 = get_term_by('slug', $x1, 'product_cat');
   $z1 = $y1->name;

   if (isset($z1)) {
      $new_breadcrumb1 = new bcn_breadcrumb($z1, NULL, array('home'), get_site_url() . '/e-shop/' . $w1 . '-' . $x1, NULL, true);
      array_splice($breadcrumb_trail->breadcrumbs, -4, 0, array($new_breadcrumb1));
   }
}

My only problem is that I cannot add the extra trail part to schema.org data (itemListElement->name). Still shows ‘E-SHOP’. It should be the category name.

We can achieve the expected output by adding the custom breadcrumb to the breadcrumb trail and also updating the schema.org data.
add_action( 'bcn_after_fill', 'my_static_breadcrumb_adder' );

function my_static_breadcrumb_adder($breadcrumb_trail) {
    $output = flrt_selected_filter_terms();

    if ( empty( $output ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $w1 = array_keys( $output )[0];
    $x1 = $output[$w1]['values'][0];
    $y1 = get_term_by( 'slug', $x1, 'product_cat' );
    $z1 = $y1->name;

    if ( isset( $z1 ) ) {
        $new_breadcrumb1 = new bcn_breadcrumb( $z1, NULL, array('taxonomy', 'product_cat' ), get_term_link( $y1 ), NULL, true );
        array_splice( $breadcrumb_trail->breadcrumbs, -1, 0, array( $new_breadcrumb1 ) );

        // Here we have updated schema.org data.
        $position = count( $breadcrumb_trail->breadcrumbs );
        $breadcrumb_trail->add( new bcn_breadcrumb( $z1, NULL, array( 'taxonomy', 'product_cat' ), get_term_link( $y1 ), NULL, true, $position ) );
    }
}


Thank you, it seems fine now. Could you please explain the object variables? I have found the source but it is not very clear. I am especially confused about the meaning of array('home') and array('taxonomy', 'product_cat'). But if you know the meaning of the other variables (including the NULL ones) please explain.

You are very welcome, array('taxonomy', 'product_cat'): Specifies the type of breadcrumb. This indicates that the breadcrumb item is related to a taxonomy term in the product_cat taxonomy.
Also you can mark this resolved if your issue has been fixed.

Be happy to but not sure how.

Here is the details regarding the same "Accepting answers
Did someone respond to a question and you find it satisfactory? Click on the check mark just to the left of the answer to show that you’ve accepted it."
https://stackoverflow.co/teams/resources/how-to-use-stack-overflow-for-teams/#:~:text=drop%20a%20comment.-,Accepting%20answers,that%20you%27ve%20accepted%20it.
